# Is the date on my Thai arrival and departure card the last day I'm allowed to be in the country or the first day I must be out of the country?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, regulations, thailand, paperwork

When arriving in Thailand, at least by land, you receive a piece of paper you should keep with your passport for when you depart. On this paper there is a date stamped.

My stamp is September 4 2013:

[image: form with stamp]

Now does this mean that I have until Sep 4 to leave, meaning if I cross the border out of Thailand at 11.50pm, 10 minutes before midnight on September 4 that all is well?

Or does it mean if I am found in Thailand at any time of the day of Sep 4 that I will be in trouble?

Comment: Umm not that it matters now but you actually get one day of grace where they don't charge you. so your millisecond idea is completely wrong. people shouldn't answer questions they don't actually know the answer to....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This visa is good until 4th of September, you can not stay beyond that. So you are safe to cross the borders until 04.SEP.2013 23:59:59.999999999 one more millisecond and you will have to pay 500 baht (15 USD?) for each day.

Anyway, I have never seen a visa which says *valid before*. It is always *valid until* to prevent confusion and fines to tourists or visitors. Also, various [LonelyPlanet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2261255) posts and [blog entries](http://www.orientexpat.com/thailand/visas/overstay) confirm this.

[image: thai stamp]

Comment: As a computer programmer we well know that ourselves and normal people are amazingly great at making "off by one errors" and you seem to hear stories about people having to pay fines or bribes for leaving countries "one day late" so I thought anything is possible. In fact when taking bookings at the hostel where I work, if the person says "until" I *always* ask them "is that the date you're departing or the last night you're sleeping?"

Comment: So I still have two days to leave Thailand (well minus 40 minutes). If I get a fine I'm sending it to you man! d-;

Comment: Sure mate, I will take care of it ;) one more thing, if you count the days manually (21 AUG - 04 SEP) the result is 15 days including the arrival day.